# How to put online image strings into SQLite database and retrive them in offline in Flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, flutter-image

I have response from an get API and the response is an array of oject. In response object,there is an image property which have online image string. I am fetching data from API and inserting then into SQLite database so that I have that data while I am offline. I don't want to store or download the image files in local folder because the number of data is around 2k. If I store that much image in asset folder, my app size will be very big. How can I get the image from database while i am offline? Should I convert the image string into BASE64 string and use Image.memory? Is it the way to do so? Below is the response I am getting from API.

```
{
"name": "Kamal",
"image": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y1yYO0X8warJliizAo5ghKRP6cFdYvb9/view?usp=sharing",
"age": 25,
"phoneNo": 156789798
}
```

**Update**:  When starting up my app, I want to fetch the image string from the database and load the in cache or any local directory for offline use. I have used **CachedNetworkImageProvider** and **cached_network_image** package. It gives me the following error

```
Exception: Could not instantiate image codec.
```

The image string which I have saved in sqlite from API is given below

```
"image": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y1yYO0X8warJliizAo5ghKRP6cFdYvb9/view?usp=sharing",
```

Comment: SQLite can store the binary data as-is. You can download the image file and store it in a BLOB column without modification. Alternatively, store it in the local file system and save the path in SQLite. You could also download it, convert it to base64 and store it in a TEXT column, but this seems like a lot of extra work for very little benefit. There are many ways to do this, pick one.

Comment: @Tomalak, is there any way I can do it without storing or downloading the image file ?

Comment: If you want to have the image available offline? Make a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue,and came up with a solution,the
concept is to fetch the image  url and saving the url on your local db and then while you are fetching the image for the 1st time you can save it in your root path directory.There is a configuration for this system.So that from the next time when the app requires to fetch the image it looks into It's offline directory 1st and then the online if image is not found.here is the code.

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;   
    class ImageCashUtil {
      ImageCashUtil() {
        init();
      }
      init() async {
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        _appDocsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        return _appDocsDir;
      }
    
      File fileFromDocsDir(String filename) {
        String pathName = p.join(_appDocsDir.path, filename);
        return File(pathName);
      }
    }
    
         Image(
                image: NetworkToFileImage(
                  url: imageUrl,
                  file: imageCashUtil.fileFromDocsDir(id),
                  debug: true,
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )
```

Comment: how do you configure the system? I wanted to save it in the cache for that I used cached_image_network but failed. Do you use  PathProvider and file system to configure the system?

Comment: child: Image(
                image: NetworkToFileImage(
                  url: imageUrl,
                  file: imageCashUtil.fileFromDocsDir(id),
                  debug: true,
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )

Comment: class ImageCashUtil {
  ImageCashUtil() {
    init();
  }
  init() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    _appDocsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return _appDocsDir;
  }

  File fileFromDocsDir(String filename) {
    String pathName = p.join(_appDocsDir.path, filename);
    return File(pathName);
  }
}

Comment: this the full code ,just copy and paste it on any dart file

Comment: I do that. But, it shows some error in the file. From where the reference p comes ?

Comment: add this import to your pubspec.yaml under depedecy path_provider: ^1.6.9